# Is it possible to have different kinds of branding per app. registration on Azure B2C?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an several clients registered in Azure AD B2C and at the moment using custom flows with federated login with local azure ad accounts.

I need to host two clients on our b2c tenants (development b2c tenant and live) that have different branding. The issue is I need to give them different background images and logos due to the clients having different branding.

Is there a sane way of solving this without having to create separate b2c tenants, just because their logos and background images differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's absolutely possible if you're using custom policies.

You first need to [create your custom branding as standalone HTML pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) that you can reference from B2C. These HTML pages will be hosted outside of B2C and could be just static HTML files or served from an app using something like ASP.NET Core.

You have two approaches you can take to serve app-specific branding using these pages, but both approaches will send the app's `client_id` (which is included in the request to B2C's `/authorize` endpoint) which your hosted pages will use to determine which branding is applied.

The first approach is to [send that `client_id` as part of the query string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#sending-query-string-parameters):

```xml
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <ContentDefinitionParameters>
        <Parameter Name="appId">{OIDC:ClientId}</Parameter>
    </ContentDefinitionParameters>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    ...
</RelyingParty>
```

You should only use this approach if you have an app (e.g. something build on ASP.NET Core) serving the HTML templates as it can read the query string from the request and serve the appropriate page back.

The second approach is to [send the `client_id` as part of the path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#dynamic-page-content-uri):

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
  <LoadUri>https://contoso.blob.core.windows.net/{OIDC:ClientId}/myHTML/unified.html</LoadUri>
  ...
</ContentDefinition>
```

This is useful when you just have static HTML files - you can have sub-folders on your HTML host site for each different `client_id` and have the HTML files within those sub-folders use the appropriate branding for that client.